# chrome.fileSystemProvider some listeners documented are not being triggered

Tags: google-chrome-app

I am following this chrome.fileSystemProvider API: https://developer.chrome.com/apps/fileSystemProvider

Many events listeners provided in this API are not being triggered for example when copying a file 'onCopyEntryRequested' listener is not being triggered.

Also when a file is opened 'onOpenFileRequested' listener is not being triggered.

Is there any solution to this?

**Update:**
I have filed bug number http://crbug.com/433337

Comment: You are aware that this API works only on Chrome OS, and is only on the dev channel? Also, inasmuch as it's experimental, it may not be fully implemented even there.

Comment: This API just got promoted so it will flow out to stable channel.As this API is so new the best place to get help with it would be at http://crbug.com. Please file a bug there and give us more details, in particular code demonstrating the problem and the version of ChromeOS you are running.

Answer (score 0):

All events are normally fired by "correct order". That is, you should implement all handlers against each event. For example, when users try to copy certain entry on the File manager app, the ChromeOS fires onGetMetadataRequested event first to confirm whether the entry which has the same name exists or not in the target location. Then, the ChromeOS will fire the onCopyEntryRequested event.

Probably, the onOpenFileRequested event is as same above.